# Awk asking combine two files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have combined two different files with Same Key by AWK command.
And In case there is no key match compare to File1 and File2 then just 
put "\t\t\t" instead.

I have below AWK command.

```
awk -F"\t" '
{key = $1}
NR == 1 {header = key}
!(key in result) {result[key] = $0 ; next}
{ for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) result[key] = result[key] FS $i }
END {
    print result[header],"\tValue2","\tValue3","\tValue4"
    delete result[header]
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"    # if using GNU awk
    for (key in result) print result[key]
}
' $1 $2 > $3
```

Example Combine
File1

```
Key    Value1
 A     10000
 B     20000
 C     30000
 D     40000
```

File2

```
 B     50000      20000     10000   
 C     20000      10000     50000
```

Then Expected result

```
Key    Value1    Value2    Value3    Value4
 A     10000       -         -         -
 B     20000     50000     20000     10000   
 C     30000     20000     10000    50000   
 D     40000       -         -         -
```

My AWK Command Show

```
Key    Value1    Value2    Value3    Value4
 A     10000       
 B     20000     50000     20000     10000   
 C     30000     20000     10000    50000   
 D     40000
```

I already tried to do few way like below

```
!(key in result) {result[key] = $0"\t-\t-\t-" ; next}
```

But looks like this is does not cover all cases.
Anyone has better idea to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: please include, (and add a comment indicating such) a record that is not covered by your `$0"\t-\t-\t-"` logic. Otherwise, excellent question. Good luck.

Comment: You may want to read up on `join`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution doesn't hardcode that there are 3 extra fields in File2

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OVS = "\t" }
    NR == FNR {
        key = $1
        $1 = ""
        store[key] = $0
        num_extra_fields = NF-1
        next
    } 
    FNR == 1 {
        printf "%s", $0
        for (i=1; i <= num_extra_fields; i++) 
            printf "%sValue%d", OFS, i+(NF-1)
        print ""
        next
    } 
    $1 in store {
        print $0  store[key]
        next
    } 
    { 
        for (i=1; i <= num_extra_fields; i++) 
            $(++NF)="-"
        print
    }
' file2 file1
```

The output looks a bit odd due to how stackoverflow displays tabs

```
Key Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
A   10000   -   -   -
B   20000   20000   10000   50000
C   30000   20000   10000   50000
D   40000   -   -   -
```

---

To fix your code, you need to keep track of the keys in file2 that update the results. Change

```
{ for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) result[key] = result[key] FS $i }
```

to

```
{ updated[key]=1; for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) result[key] = result[key] FS $i }
```

and, in the END block, change

```
  for (key in result) print result[key]
```

to

```
  for (key in result) {
    if (!(key in updated)) result[key] = result[key] FS "-" FS "-" FS "-"
    print result[key]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I check with your solution looks like there is no data came out. Do you have any idea to put from previous my code? This case Column is always fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR {if (!n) {n=NF-1; s="-"; for(i=2; i<=n; i++) s=s OFS "-"}
   a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{sub($1, "&" OFS $2, a[$1]);
   print a[$1]; next} {print $0, s}' file2 file1

A   10000   -       -       -
B   20000   50000   20000   10000
C   30000   20000   10000   50000
D   40000   -       -       -
```