# AWK compare two columns form different files and merge outputs

Tags: bash, file, awk

I need help :)
I have two files (both very large).

**file1:**

```
1a04    1a04
9   161.9
10  143.5
11  146.8
12  111.5
13  100.2
14  75.2
15  46.1
16  90.3
17  93.3
18  119.9
19  178.9
20  171.4
21  168.4
22  169.0
23  176.4
24  167.0
25  164.5
```

**file2**

```
1a04    1a04
5   0
6   -
7   E
8   E
9   E
10  E
11  E
12  E
13  -
14  S
15  >>
16  H
17  H
18  H
19  H
20  H
```

I want to compare the first columns of the two files and, if they match, merge them in a new file.
So the desired output I need is:

```
1a04  1a04  1A04
9   161.9  E
10  143.5  E
11  146.8  E
12  111.5  E
13  100.2  -
14  75.2   S
15  46.1   >>
16  90.3   H
17  93.3   H
18  119.9  H
19  178.9  H
20  171.4  H
```

I have tried multiple awk combination, but I couldn't get the exact output I want
Thanks for your help

Comment: Consider the (POSIX) [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) command instead of `awk`.  Assuming the files, `file1` and `file2`, are in sorted order, `join -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 file1 file2`.  If they're not in sorted order, sort them first, or use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution): `join -o1.1,1.2,2.2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I can't sort them, unfortunately, that's the reason I am looking for and awk solution

Comment: Why can't you sort them?  GIven the sample data, the `join` command shown produces the output you want — give or take the spacing between columns (which is erratic and hence extraordinarily difficult to reproduce exactly).

Comment: duplicate question to https://stackoverflow.com/q/29476542/6266192

Comment: I can't because I have multiple header lines (e.g: 1a04  1a04 ) along the file, that are deleted when I try the join command.

Comment: Your output includes a heading that isn't present in the data (`1A04` vs `1a04`). Your problem description doesn't mention that there is a heading line in the data. There are ways (not particularly beautiful ways, but ways nonetheless) of ensuring header lines stay at the top of the sorted data for a file, such as `(sed 1q file1; sed 1d file1 | sort)`, though, with enough care, you can avoid two `sed` commands, especially if you use Perl instead. The two-`sed` technique does require 'real' files; it won't work in a pipeline, or with terminal input.

Answer (score 2):

Using 2 phase `awk` it would be:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { map[$1]=$2; next} $1 in map { print $0, map[$1] }' file2 file1 |
column -t
```

```
1a04  1a04   1a04
9     161.9  E
10    143.5  E
11    146.8  E
12    111.5  E
13    100.2  -
14    75.2   S
15    46.1   >>
16    90.3   H
17    93.3   H
18    119.9  H
19    178.9  H
20    171.4  H
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried your suggestion but It does not seem to work to me  ```1a04  1a04   1a04
9     161.9  S
10    143.5  G
11    146.8  G
12    111.5  G
13    100.2  S
14    75.2   >
15    46.1   H
16    90.3   H
17    93.3   H
18    119.9  H
19    178.9  H
20    171.4  H
21    168.4  T
22    169.0  T
23    176.4  T
24    167.0  T
25    164.5  S ```

Comment: Output from your sample files is attached in answer, does it not match your expected output? Check your input files to make sure both files have 2 columns and there is no DOS line ending in any of them.

Comment: Yes, when I try to extend it to the whole file, the output is completely different (I attached you only the portion of the sample files ).

Comment: Then provide a small sample of actual data in question. I cannot guess a solution without seeing actual data.

Comment: https://gofile.io/d/zcwtkK

Comment: @Fede: Hmmm — 34 MiB or so of data in two files.  No explanation of what goes wrong.    That kinda makes it tricky to help you.  You should be creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
You may still need an external site to host the data, but it shouldn't take 34 MiB to show the problem.

Comment: I managed to use the join command. thanks to all