# awk union two columns from different output files

Tags: bash, git, awk

I'm working on combine `git status` and `git diff -stat` to show modified-type and line-changes.

- output1 ( from `$ git status -sb` )

  ```
  ## main
  M a
  ?? b
  ```
- output2 ( from `$ git --no-pager diff --stat | head -n-1`, cannot show new files )

  ```
  a | 2 ++
  ```

[image]

the expected final result should be :

```
## main              # header from output1 NR==1
 M a | 2 ++          # output1 $1 + output2 $0; or output1 $0 + output2 $2,$3
?? b                 # if output1 $2 cannot be found in output2 $1, then print output1 $0
```

<strike>I was fighting for long time according to [Awk asking combine two files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29476542/2940319), but stills in stucking</strike>

And how can I keep the ansicolor from git output? Is it possible to call `awk` like :

```
$ awk '...' <(git status -sb) <(git --no-pager diff --stat | head -n-1)
```

### UPDATE-1

I get clue from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14984673/2940319 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64139395/2940319, and noticed that:

- `FNR == NR` : read 1st file
- `FNR != NR`: read 2nd file

So the following code works ( ya, I know, it's ugly ):

```
awk 'FNR==NR { map[$1]=$2" "$3" "$4 }
     FNR != NR { if ($2 in map) {print $0, map[$2]} else { print $0 } }
    ' <(git --no-pager diff --stat --relative | head -n-1) <(git status -sb)

## main
 M a | 2 ++
?? b
```

Is there any elegant way to achieve it ?

[image]

### UPDATE 2

I've encounter another issue by using awk, which is if there's only new file added, which output2 ( `git --no-pager diff --stat | head -n-1` ) is empty, there's nothing shows up, because of the commands :

```
awk '...' output2 output1
#            ^ missing output2
# commands becomes

awk '...' output1
```

I'm currently using bash to handle it:

```
if [[ -z ... ]]; then
  git status -sb
else
  awk ... <(git diff ..) <(git status ..)
done
```

any awk solution for this?

### UPDATE 3

I've tried to using awk to resolve if `output1` is missing, by using `awk '...'  as below, however it will cause output append to the final line when` FNR!=NR`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR { map[$2]=$0; printf ("\n%s ", $0) } { if ($1 in map) print $2,$3,$4 }' <(echo -e '## main\nM a\n?? c\n?? d') <(echo 'a | 2 ++')

## main
M a
?? c
?? d | 2 ++         #  ` | 2 ++` should be append to `M 2`
```

because it handle the `FNR==NR` first. So here is my solution, thanks @jhnc for awk elegant awk solution

```
declare gdiff
gdiff=$(git --no-pager diff --stat --relative | head -n-1)
awk 'FNR==NR { k=$1; $1=""; map[k]=$0; next } { print $0 map[$2] }' \
    <(echo -e "${gdiff}") <(git status -sb)
#       ^ even `gdiff` is empty, it will still keeps the first parma of awk
```

[image]

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR&&/[|]/ {v[$1]=$0;next} $1=="M" && $2 in v {$0=" M"v[$2]} 1' <(git --no-pager diff --stat) <(git status -sb)` ?

Comment: Hey @jhnc, looks like it only handle the `git status -sb`, `| ...` from `git diff` not shown

Comment: @jhnc, the following code works `awk 'FNR==NR { map[$1]=$2" "$3" "$4 } FNR != NR { if ($2 in map) {print $0, map[$2]} else { print $0 } }' <(git --no-pager diff --stat | head -n-1 ) <(git status -sb)`, but I'm looking for any elegant solution ?

Comment: `awk 'FNR==NR { k=$1; $1=""; map[k]=$0; next } { print $0 map[$2] }' f2 f1` ? (creates empty elements but probably not an issue unless the git output is really huge)

Comment: wow !! nice @jhnc !! please submit your solution as answer, I  will accept it. another issue, if repo has only new files, which mens `f2` is empty, I'd like to show all in `f1`, is there any awk solution for this ?

Comment: problem details should be provided in the question, not in comments. you can add extra example input/output to the existing question to clarify it, or ask a new question if it is about a different problem

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I think my code always shows entirety of `f1`, it just appends to some lines based on contents of `f2`

Comment: yes, @jhnc, in normal status `$ awk '...' <(echo 'a | 2 ++') <(echo 'M a')` works (result: `M a | 2 ++`), and `$ awk '...' <(echo '') <(echo 'M a')` works as well ( result `M a` ). the issue is, when `git diff` is empty, the cmd is `$ awk '...' <(echo 'M a')`, which is only 1 file, not 2 files. so it has to be `$ awk '...' f1 f2`, because of when f2 is empty it will still work. Still really appreciate for your comments, please submit your solution as answer

Comment: Hi @jhnc, I've resolved the issue by pre-define the `gdiff` string and using `<(echo -e "${gdiff}")`, it will prevent missing `f2` to awk analysis. check details: [solution](https://github.com/marslo/dotfiles/blob/main/.marslo/bin/git-st) or [solution-2](https://github.com/marslo/dotfiles/blob/3fa0e53b36106770d170361cb24c51fb2f9c6e21/.marslo/bin/git-st)

Answer (score 0):

> can I keep the ansicolor from git output?

ANSI escape codes are just part of text, for example in colour-supporting terminal emulator

```
echo -e "\033[31mtest123\033[0m" | awk '{print $0}'
```

does output `test123` using red characters, `echo -e` stands for any command using ANSI escape codes. Keep in mind that you must take this into account for example

```
echo -e "\033[31mtest123\033[0m" | awk '$0=="test123"'
```

will give empty output. Be warned some commands will automatically disengage color codes when their output is shoved into pipe, for example GNU `grep`

```
grep -o '[0-9]' file.txt
```

will output colored digits from `file.txt`, whilst

```
grep -o '[0-9]' file.txt | awk '{print $0}'
```

will give same digits but without coloring. I do not know if `git` does behave this way, but before you go further I suggest summoning `git` ninja able to tell that.

Comment: I was worry about the ansicolor impacted awk column thing, but looks like it works well :). thanks.